# What end user metadata can be gained through FCM token

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging

Working on a privacy focused messaging app and I have certain questions regarding privacy if using FCM.
Maninly Id like to know what metadata Google and its services might be able to gain from a given token. Would this make it possible to link a given token to the Google account of an end user? I would think FCM tokens are logged by Google Play services and would therefore be a direct link between App instance and Google account.

I have been looking through the documentation but havent been able to find an answere, so if anyone konws or could point me in the right direction Id appreciate it